# Will SSD silent my computer?

Tags: hard-drive, memory, ssd, cpu

Do you think my computer will be silent if I replace my HDD with a SSD? Actually, I realise thanks to Task Manager that only my HD is (most of time) 100% used when CPU and memory are only 10 to 15%. I have a i7 (8 cores) Toshiba computer. 
Thanks

Comment: Its a little less noise, but a HDD usually doesnt make much noise to begin with.  Most of the noise comes from the fans in your machine.

Comment: @CheesusCrust it really depends on the harddisk. I've had a few harddisks in my hands that were very noisy. Sometimes the vibrations of the harddisk were transferred in the case. So in these regards, an SSD will definitely make a difference. An SSD is always quiet. (no mechanical parts)

Comment: @LPChip thank for your reply yet don't you really think it may depend on the fan too? because I don't want to invest on a new disk when the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, it is most likely the fan, but my comment is directly answering your question, not any other components. I felt I didn't need to given that Cheesus Crust already mentioned that. My comment was more an addendum to his.

Comment: @duhamel if you do go the fan route bear in mind that generally larger fans at a lower rpm are quieter than small ones at higher rpm for the same air flow.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, no it won't make your computer silent.  In general, unless you're dealing with 15k RPM enterprise hard drives, your fans are going to be noisier than your hard disk (if you have no fans though, and have a power supply that doesn't make any noise (a lot of cheap ones hum), it might make the system silent other than the keyboard and mouse).

An SSD will probably reduce the noise your system produces, and is likely a good investment for other reasons too (it will reduce your power consumption and most likely speed up your system).

Comment: Thanks first. I actually discovered yesterday by opening and screening what was really going on. I was really astonished when I saw that the fan was the reason of the noise. When I held the fan with my finger, no noise anymore, not even the HDD. So at a certain moment, I was tempted to disconnect the fan a use my computer like that but I wonder if it's a good idea since after holding the fan for couple of seconds, I got an alert from the OS. What do you think ? Thanks